# Jdbi3: transaction with more than one dao and @Transaction annotation

Tags: java, jdbi, jdbi3

I have to execute a transactions that involves methods in more than one dao, so I am using something like:

```
    jdbi.useHandle(handle -> {

        handle.useTransaction(h -> {

            Dao1 dao1 = h.attach(Dao1.class);
            Dao2 dao2 = h.attach(Dao2.class);
            dao1.method1();
            dao2.method2();
        });
    });
```

but if for example in `Dao1` method1 is annotated with `@Transaction`, like:

```
public interface Dao1 {

   @SqlUpdate
   @Transaction
   public void method1();
}
```

The above handle parts will execute both the methods in the same transaction?
Or method1 will open a new transaction during execution?

Answer (score 1):

Do not use @Transaction annotation if you want to reuse DAO methods in another transaction. This makes slow performance and complicated checkpoints for rollbacks, if DBMS can support, it causes exceptions.